# Linear Operator and isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I wanted to be sure about the following:

Let's say we have vector spaces normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a linear operator $T:X \rightarrow Y$.
My idea was to reduce the properties that I need to show of the following two types of linear operators:

Then T is a isomorphism (continuous and bijective) if we have that $T$ is continuous + surjective and $T^{-1}$ is continuous. Correct?
Afais $||T^{-1}x||\le ||T^{-1}||||x||$ should imply that $T$ is injective.Hence, $T$ is a bijection. Hence, $T$ is a isomorophism.

$T$ is an isometric isomorphism if $||Tx||=||x||$ and $T$ is surjective. Correct? Cause I think this implies that $T$ is injective and that $T^{-1}$ is also an isometric isomorphism.

Comment: If $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ and $T$ is onto, then $T$ is an isomorphism, and $T^{-1}$ is an isomorphism. If $X$ and $Y$ are complete (i.e. Banach) spaces, if $T : X\rightarrow Y$ is linear, onto and continuous, then $T^{-1}$ is automatically continuous by the Closed Graph Theorem.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @T.A.E. thank you. this answers my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be really sure about this, you have to also be sure you are using the word "inverse" correctly. There are ordinary inverses, [left inverses and right inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses): two of these three imply (by their very existence) that $T$ is injective, but the last one does not.

If $T^{-1}$ means the ordinary inverse (as it should), then note that saying "$T^{-1}$ is continuous" contains a sub-statement: "$T^{-1}$ exists". This sub-statement implies the  injectivity of $T$, without any norms entering the picture.